# SQL query similar to distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table (c1, c2) with the values (1,1) (1,4), (4,1) (2,2), what query would allow me to only output the results where c2 =1 and there only exists one entry for it in the table?  In this case it would only be (4,1), since there's two entries where c1 =1.
Cheers.

Comment: "In this case it would only be (4,1)" - Why not (1,1)?

Comment: My wording was likely a bit off, but I meant that since there's two entries where c1 =1 they're not included.

Comment: Then please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. there are many ways. Here's one:

```
select c1, c2
from my_table t1
where c2 = 1
  and 1 = (select count(*) from my_table t2 where t2.c1 = t1.c1)
```

Some other ways:

```
select t1.c1, t1.c2
from my_table t1
join my_table t2 using (c1)
where t1.c2 = 1
group by t1.c1, t1.c2
having count(*) = 1;
```

```
select c1, c2
from my_table t1
where c2 = 1
  and not exists (
      select *
      from from my_table t2
      where t2.c1 =  t1.c1
        and t2.c2 <> t1.c2
  );
```

```
select t1.c1, t1.c2
from my_table t1
left join my_table t2
  on  t2.c1 =  t1.c1
  and t2.c2 <> t1.c2
where t1.c2 = 1
  and t2.c1 is null;
```

The last two queries require to have no duplicates in your table.

Comment: The second example as it is does not return anything(at list in MySQL, as from the tag), that because you did not have missed group by. Then to correct it should be select t1.c1 c1, t1.c2 c2
from my_table t1
join my_table t2 using (c1)
where t1.c2 = 1
group by c1,c2
having count(*) = 1;